# GGplot scatterplot color interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im currently getting back into using R, but its been a while so im a little rusty.

I have the following code for making plots using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(NewData, aes(x=PAH16Cons ,y=Depth, group(FileName)))+
                geom_point(aes(colour=PAH16Cons))+
                scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse")+
                facet_wrap(facets = vars(FileName))+
                scale_color_gradient2("Cons mg/kg ts", 
                                      breaks =c(0,100,500),
                                      low = 'green',
                                      mid = 'yellow',
                                      high = 'red')
```

Im trying to change the color of the plot so values between 0-100 are green, 100-500 yellow and above 500 red. [image]

But, as you can see I get no green, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to set the `midpoint` which by default is equal to `0`. That's why your gradient starts at yellow.

Comment: Ohh, i see.. So if i want to get all values below 100 to be one shade of green, all values between 100 and 500 one shade of yellow and all above 500 one shade of red, this is not the way?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to use color gradients or single color shades? If you want to use single colors to represent three groups of values, then you should use `scale_color_manual()` instead of `scale_color_gradient2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use one color shade for each range of values, you can create a grouping (factor) column with levels on the condition of `PAH16Cons` values <100, 100-500, or >500. Afterwards, use this column for the `color` aesthetics in the `ggplot` and use `scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "yellow", "red"))` to customize the color.

```r
NewData$cols <- with(NewData, 
    factor(
        ifelse(PAH16Cons < 100, "<100", 
            ifelse(PAH16Cons >= 100 & PAH16Cons <= 500, "100-500", ">500")), 
        levels = c("<100", "100-500", ">500")))

ggplot(NewData, aes(x=PAH16Cons ,y=Depth, group(FileName)))+
    geom_point(aes(colour=cols))+
    scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse")+
    facet_wrap(facets = vars(FileName))+
    scale_color_manual("Cons mg/kg ts", values=c("green", "yellow", "red"))
```

Run `?scale_color_manual` for more information and examples.